Link multiple planes through edges extrution
I have a series of planes along the line but I don't know the position of the vertices of each plane. What I want to do is link the planes to each other through the edge extrusion. I try to do that using the code below:
import bpy
import bmesh

# Check if the object exists
section_1 = bpy.data.objects["Plane"]
section_2 = bpy.data.objects["Plane.001"]
# Ensure we're in object mode
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')

# Set the active object
bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = section_1
section_1.select_set(True)

# Switch to edit mode
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')

# Create a BMesh from the object's mesh
bm1 = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(section_1.data)
bm2 = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(section_2.data)

for vertex in bm2.vertices:
    vertex_coords = vertex.co
print(f"verteces positions are {vertex_coords}")    
# Select all edges in the mesh
for edge in bm1.edges:
    edge.select = True

# Extrude the selected edges
bpy.ops.mesh.extrude_region_move(
    MESH_OT_extrude_region={"use_normal_flip": False, "use_dissolve_ortho_edges": False, "mirror": False},
    TRANSFORM_OT_translate={
        "value": (20, 0, 0),  # Move in the x direction
        "orient_type": 'GLOBAL',
        "constraint_axis": (True, False, False),  # Constrain to the X-axis
        "snap": True,
        "snap_elements": {'VERTEX'},
    }
)

# Deselect all edges after extrusion
for edge in bm1.edges:
    edge.select = False

# Update the mesh and return to object mode
bmesh.update_edit_mesh(section_1.data)
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')

The code is concerned with the easiest case. Thank you in advance!

Hello, it's really hard to understand what this script does. Could you add a screenshot of your setup and another with an example of what you want to achieve ?

@Gorgious as shown in the figure I have that series of planes, I want to link the edges with each other to build a solid in an automatic way

I don't know python, but you can't link the edges of individual objects without first joining them all together into a single object using Ctrl-J.

@JohnEason in this case, how does it work?

How does what work? - As I said, I don't know python but using normal modelling, selecting two planes in Blender and going into Edit mode you will not be able to merge the vertices from the two planes even though they are both editable. They still remain seperate objects and I assume the same would apply if you tried to 'link' them using python.
